# Extjs 4, encode form item

Tags: encoding, extjs4

How to encode **htmleditor** body before submit form? (**Ext.form.Panel**)

Comment: HtmlEncode, escape html, something like this)

Comment: DmitryB, no. "Request Validation has detected a potentially dangerous client input value"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**byte_slave** thank you, but

```
var form = this.up('form').getForm();
var old = form.findField('body').getValue();
old = Ext.util.Format.htmlEncode(oldBodyValue);
form.findField('body').setValue(old);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Base64 encoding before you submit your form and then decode it on server side.